# Как обработать код уже открытой страницы с помощью selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

Я работаю в браузере Chrome с помощью selenium webdriver + Python. Сайт, с которым моя программа должна работать, каждый раз требует авторизации. Моя программа прекрасно авторизовывается и попадает на главную страницу Сайта. Но необходимо, чтобы программа могла и на главной странице кое-что нажать, перейти на другую страницу и там тоже кое-что нажать, и дальше в том же духе. Однако для взаимодействия с главной и последующими страницами необходимо сначала обработать функцией driver.get() код страницы. Когда я вызываю driver.get(), он перезагружает Сайт и мне заново выдаëтся страница авторизации, а мне нужно, чтобы программа обработала новую страницу Сайта без перезагрузки, нажала на кнопку и перешла на следующую страницу. Как это сделать?
код:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options  
chrome_options = Options() 
chrome_options.add_argument("By")  
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/chromedriver.exe", 
options=chrome_options) 
driver.get("https://...") 
login = driver.find_element("name", "login") 
login.send_keys("...") 
password = driver.find_element("name", "password")                             
password.send_keys("....") 
password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN) 
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
```

Comment: Непонятно. Что вы имете ввиду, когда пишете 'обработать страницу'?

Comment: Это то же самое, что "обработать код страницы функцией driver.get()". После этого webdriver может взаимодействовать с сайтом.

Comment: Это не проясняет ситуацию. Покажите как эта обработка выглядит в коде.

Comment: @Roman-Stop RU aggression in UA
`from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("By")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/chromedriver.exe", options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://...")
login = driver.find_element("name", "login")
login.send_keys("...")
password = driver.find_element("name", "password")
password.send_keys("....")
password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source   `

Comment: Только код смазался, у меня всё распределено по отдельным строкам.

Comment: все это добавляйте в текст вопроса кнопкой "править"